# current_user helper method returning error in mongoid backed authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using omniauth-twitter gem for authentication. And my rails app is backed by Mongodb.

When clicked on **Login** it opened the twitter profile. I entered the credentials and got redirected back to the app with an error saying

```
unknown operator: $oid (2)

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

    helper_method :current_user
```

It is pointing error at the `@current_user` line. But when I checked the database for the user created by doing `User.last`, I can see a user object.

**User.rb** file

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :provider, type: String
  field :uid, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :location, type: String
  field :image_url, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  index({ provider: 1, uid: 1 }, { unique: true})

  class << self
      def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
        user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
        user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
        user.location = auth_hash['info']['location']
        user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
        user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['Twitter']
        user.save!
        user
      end
  end
end
```

Then I created a sessions controller and looks as follows.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    begin
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
      rescue
        flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    if current_user
     session.delete(:user_id)
     flash[:success] = 'See you!'
    end
   redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Can someone please help me fix this ?

Comment: Where have you defined current_user method ?

Comment: Have you followed a tutorial like this ? https://www.ultrasaurus.com/2013/10/rails-4-twitter-omniauth-with-mongodb/ Tell us a bit more :)

Comment: I defined `current_user` In application_controller.rb file.

Comment: What about the rest of the oAuth related code ?

Comment: No I followed this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/. But he is using Mysql, and I am using mongodb.

Comment: Let me add all the changes I did for omniauth.

Comment: oAuth related code added. Please have a look

Comment: Poorly I am not a MongoDB expert. I have seen the error `unknown operator: $oid` when the Object ID of the saved element is not in string format, but don't ask me how to solve ! Sorry, maybe someone else has a clue.

Comment: I think you should follow a tutorial where they use MongoDB instead of mysql or pg -> http://railsapps.github.io/tutorial-rails-mongoid-omniauth.html

Comment: what is the error message returned from mongoid? as this is triggered from `User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])` my understanding

Comment: I have posted the error. The first code snippet.